# If the distribution of returns in symmetric, why not use a coin toss, small risk & high reward?

Tags: random-walk

If the distribution of returns is symmetric then why not

1. use a coin toss to decide whether to buy or sell
2. Calculate the average velocity of the market (ATR - in technical analysis)
3. Place a stop loss on 0.5 ATR away from current price and take a profit 2 ATR away from the current price?

I tried it in FOREX and it doesn't seem to work. Why is this so?

Comment: Returns do not appear to be symmetric.

Comment: Your strategy seems equivalent to the following:
the price $X_t$ is a standard random walk, 
you buy at $t=0$
and sell when it reaches -1/2 or 2 (whichever comes first).
In this case, the expected profit is zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several reasons:

**Expected payoff = 0**

I don't know why you selected 0.5 ATR and 2 ATR away from the market but let's go with it for a while. This means that you want to gain 2x while risking only 0.5x. For now let's assume that FX log-returns are normal.

To bring it to a higher level, we can use a piece of Black Scholes formula, namely the probability that an option ends up in the money is N(d$_{2}$) where N(*) is a cumulative normal distribution of a function and d2 is a function defined as in BS. So your expected payoff is E[payoff] = 2*N(d$_{2}$(2)) - 0.5*N(d$_{2}$(0.5)) which equals 0 if you do the calculation. This explains why you don't make money, not why in reality you lose money. Read on.

**Returns are not normally distributed**

In general, normal distribution is not a good representation of FX (or other) log-returns. The real distribution of returns has fat tails, often skewness, prices have jumps etc. If the assumption of normality is rejected, your model breaks down.

**Transaction costs**

As edouard mentioned, even if your E[payoff] = 0, you would incur transaction costs (through slippage, fees, bid/ask spread etc.) which would make your E[payoff] < 0.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

could this strategy be applied for real trading ?

i mean, whatever a trade makes or loses money, trading incurs transaction-costs.

thus, you cannot stand on that (perfect) bell-shaped distribution to trade profitably with any certainty.